# Which regular expression flavour is used by the MediaWiki search and replace dialog?

Tags: mediawiki, regex

I recently discovered this search and replace dialog in MediaWiki and have been using it more and more:

[image: MediaWiki search and replace dialog]

But I can't seem to find the documentation on it. On the MediaWiki website I always find info about some extension that does search and replace over an entire wiki when I try to search for this.

I can't tell which regex dialect the dialog uses or which regex features it does and doesn't support. It ought most likely to be JavaScript's dialect yet `^` didn't seem to work nor did other things I tried, so now I'm looking to read the manual, if there is one ...

Comment: Note, that's provided by WikiEditor. https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:WikiEditor

Comment: @Nemo: I was too dim to find this dialog or its regex documented there either. Could you point it out for me?

Comment: It's not documented indeed. :) I only pointed out to ease other people's code and issue tracker inspections. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is [a plain Javascript regex](https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki-extensions-WikiEditor/blob/d3b0ef6c2771ec4ddf1d6d35f3e5cb9fa36034a6/modules/jquery.wikiEditor.dialogs.config.js#L1169). You probably made some kind of typo.

Comment: No it turned out to be a known bug: https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T58228